# Why does console.log() output [object Object] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(({
  title: "The Three Musketeers",
  author: "Alexandre Dumas",
  price: "$49"
}).toString());
```

It outputs an Object as `[object Object]`, even though I am calling .toString() on it. Can anyone please explain why this happens?

Comment: What did you expect it to print and why did you expect that?

Comment: Your object does not have its own `toString`, so it uses the one from object.

Comment: Because that's what [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object) says it should return. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for have built a JavaScript object that you are attempt to convert to a string. You are attempting to convert the entire **object** to a string, which can't (really) be done. As such, you simply get text that says "Hey, we've got an object here".

If however, you were to run `.toString()` on a **property** of that object (which is probably your intent), you would get a string representation of that property. This can be done by accessing the proeprty with the dot notation just before calling `.toString()`, as follows:

```js
console.log(({
  title: "The Three Musketeers",
  author: "Alexandre Dumas",
  price: "$49"
}).title.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you try to convert or add an object to a string (which also tries to convert it to a string), what you're looking for is `JSON.stringify(object)` :

```js
console.log(
    JSON.stringify(
        {title : "The Three Musketeers", author: "Alexandre Dumas", price: "$49"}
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a JSON string representation of the object, look into [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way it will work better

```
let object = {
  title: "The Three Musketeers",
  author: "Alexandre Dumas",
  price: "$49"
}
console.log("My object",object);
```

It's because it doesn't know how to render your object

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is JSON.stringify(). Try this:

```
JSON.stringify({
  title: "The Three Musketeers",
  author: "Alexandre Dumas",
  price: "$49"
}, null, 2);
```